# QTextDocument: get words with specific format

Tags: qt, formatting, qtextdocument

I have a QTextDocument with some text where part of the text is underlined (misspellings).
I want to parse the text and get the as formated words with positions.
How?

```
for( auto textBlock = document()->begin(); textBlock != document()->end(); textBlock = textBlock.next() )
        {
            qDebug() << "textBlock::text: " << textBlock.text();
            for (auto t = textBlock.begin(); t != textBlock.end(); ++t)
            {
                qDebug() << "";
                auto fragment = t.fragment();
                qDebug() << fragment.text();
                auto format = fragment.charFormat();
                qDebug() << format.fontUnderline();
                qDebug() << format.underlineStyle();
                qDebug() << format.underlineColor();
                qDebug() << "";
            }
        }
```

But this always outputs:

1. the entire content of QTextDocument.
2. No underline, no style...

So apparently I need to eithet get it another way, or somehow get deeper? How?

Comment: QTextEdit::document()->textCursor().block().layout()->formats();